# Looking at the ExpectedConditions class, trying to find onChange

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I noticed in the application I am working on testing, when I click a submit button a grid refreshes.  I have a rowcount I have access to in a span, and wanted to do something like:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, upperTimeoutLimit))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementChanged(By.cssSelector(mySelector)));
```

My goal is to look at a node and do a WebDriverWait until it changes in someway, ideally the *getText*

*edit* I was talking to @FlorentB and he was mentioning something along the following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, upperTimeoutLimit);
WebElement grid = ui.getExternalCommandGrid();
submit.click();
//staleness
System.out.println("about to check for staleness");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(grid));
System.out.println("About to check presence of");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
   By.cssSelector(ui.getExternalCommandGridSizeSelector())));
```

It doesnt seem to get passed the stalenessOf(grid) part. My thought may be that i select the grid prior to the click, run the click, and then was hoping it would wait until it recognized a change (Maybe i need to check rows instead) before getting the next piece of the puzzle.

Comment: There are many conditions in the API itself which u can use - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html.... textMatches, textToBe,  textToBePresentInElement, textToBePresentInElementLocated,  textToBePresentInElementValue etc

Comment: can i use text match to check for a "textNotMatches", but yes i have been looking at that API and trying to think what i can leverage for my situation

Comment: Combine it with the not() ExpectedCondition which will give you the logical opposite. ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedCondition.textMatches()) should do the trick

Comment: Do you want to wait until element change their innerText from present to new text?? Right

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I want to monitor the span for a change in inner text which would allow the Webdriver to continue.

Comment: @Grasshopper can you create an example for me?  Seems like mine keeps throwing errors.  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textMatches(
                By.cssSelector(mySelector), new Pattern(oldValue))));`

Comment: @Fallenreaper  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.cssSelector(mySelector), oldValue)));    If you have a textbox or textarea use this instead textToBePresentInElementValue. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Got it working!

Comment: @Fallenreaper Which one worked?

Comment: @Grasshopper I posted the example, but if you post it, i will give you credit.   The ExpectedContion.not works as the answer to solve my specific problem.  Now, i have other problems I will have to write some new questions for but ultimately that resolved it.

Comment: @Fallenreaper No point in repeating the answer twice, its already there... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I ended up getting this to work would be as follows:

```
//submit is a button.
//driver is a WebDriver.
//uppderTimeoutLimit is an int, 10000
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, upperTimeoutLimit);
WebElement sizeEle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector));
String beforeCount = sizeEle.getText();
submit.click();
System.out.println("about to wait until change");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textMatches(
        By.cssSelector(selector),
        Pattern.compile(beforeCount))));
```

It will timeout if it doesnt change, and if it does, it will continue on.  Now the only thing i can think to do is to say wrap it with a try, because if it timesout, i would like some human readable content to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to wait for the grid to be refreshed would be to wait for the staleness of the located element within the grid:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// element in grid
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(mySelector));

// trigger the reload
button.click();

// waits for the element to become stale
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));

// waits for a new element
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(mySelector)));
```

Comment: What is "staleness"?  I was not sure how it was defined.  I saw it, but wasnt sure if it was needed to be toggled in some way.

Comment: The result returned by `findElement` is a reference to an `HTMLElement` from the page. It is stored in `WebElement.id`. This reference becomes stale (no longer usable)
when the document is reloaded or if the element is removed from the page or replaced.

Comment: Oh, so if the text changes, etc etc, it would become stale?   Im going to test this, and then if it works, this is the answer I was wanting.

Comment: The element won't become stale if the page only updates the inner text. But in most cases, the whole grid is recreated, making all the rows stale.

Comment: Dang.  Yeah, I was just seeing it would still timeout.  Maybe ill just go a bit bigger, and check staleness of the grid.  ill follow up with you when i get it working

Comment: Seems like i have issues checking staleness in Polymer Based applications.  I ran: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(grid));` to see when that would work, but that fails to get staleness.  Ill make an edit to better explain.

Comment: In your case I would wait for the first row to become stale before processing the next page and not the grid. However it might not work if the page reuse the exiting rows to build the new grid. If it's the case, you need wait for an element in your page indicating that the page was updated. Note that I wouldn't recommend to wait for the the number of rows to change since an update could result in same number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such option like elementChanged in selenium. You can do this in your own way. First, get the grid's row count before clicking your submit button. Then wait for number of elements to be greater than the previous count.

```
 //count the grid's row before clicking submit button
 int previousRowCount = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("your selector  for row")).size();

 //click submit button & wait for grid's row count to be greater than previousRowCount
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.cssSelector("your table rows locator"), numberCountBeforeTableLoad));
```

**Addition:**

All these methods wait for a maximum amount of time given as argument. You can't wait for your page/element load for infinite time. In one of my projects, there were a lot of data loaded into table. While sorting data, table gets disappeared. So, I did a trick. First, I waited for invisibility of the table/rows and then for visibility of the same thing for maximum of 5 minitues (yes, it was really five minitues!!). And, it worked for me.

Comment: That is what i do right now, with a longer wait, the issue is that the network request takes a variable amount of time, which is what i am trying to circumvent.  I am trying to get around a wait of a hard amount of time by something a bit more dynamic.  The elements to be more than, cant work because It is paging, so it will have up to 100 rows per page, and if it is as 270 rows, it wont show a row count change if the page reloads.

Comment: What if the row count decreases or doesn't change? The elements may have updated but the count may not change in the way you expect. You really should do this a different way to be safe.

Comment: Does your table/grid disappear after clicking submit button? Then, wait for invisibility & visibility of the table/table rows respectively.